# Modulus of a complex sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, complex-numbers, cauchy-sequences

Let $z$ be a complex number, $a$ a real number. Define $x_n=(a\cdot z)^n$. Find an expression for $|x_n|$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

How should I understand this question? I already got the polarform of $z$. Should that be used here. The notation of finding the modulus of a sequence for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is throwing me off. What does this mean?

Comment: as I understand it you should find a function $f(n)=|x_n|=|(a\cdot z)^n|$ where $n\in\Bbb N$

Comment: @sortai if $z=\sqrt(3)\frac{5}{12}+i\frac{5}{12}$ what would that look like then? I am not quite getting the gist of it.

Comment: @sortai Isn't it the modulus of said complex number?

Comment: yes, you can simplify it though. I think, more accurately than I said before, it's a function of a, z and n.

Comment: I think I get where the problem is, you're interpreting $|x_n|$ as the modulus of a sequence, when really you need to find an expression that generates the sequence of moduli, or at least that's what I gather from the text.

Comment: Oh now I see. So the expression is basically just "pluging in z" and then I should be done right?

Comment: yup. btw, you can express this in a way that completely ignores the argument of z

Comment: I think that is what I need. You can see my other post as to the follow up question where - I think! - this result is needed. (pretty certain). The link is here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4129199/convergence-of-a-sequence-for-a-real-number-b - I am really new as you can see haha.