# Convergence of a Sequence for a real number $b$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, cauchy-sequences

Let $z=\sqrt(3)\frac{5}{12}+i\frac{5}{12}$ and let $b\in \mathbb{R}$. Define $x_n=(b\cdot z)^n$.

- Determine all real $b$ where $\left \{ x_n \right \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is convergent
- Determine all real $b$ where $\left \{ x_n \right \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ has a convergent subsequence

How do I even start to argue for this? I know that any bounded complex sequence has a convergent subsequence but that is not useful as I need to handle problem one first. I have found the argument of $z$ and the modulus of $z$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

1. if $|bz|<1$, then $x_n \to 0$
2. if $|bz|>1$, then $|x_n| \to \infty.$
3. if $|bz|=1$, then $|x_n|=1$ for all $n$, hence $(x_n)$ is bounded.

Comment: In the 3 cases; how do I argue for this? How do I know which $b$ gives me thoes outcomes? and is $|x_n|$ just equal to $|(b \cdot (\sqrt(3)\frac{5}{12}+i\frac{5}{12}))^n|$?

Comment: Show that $|z|= \frac{5}{6}$.Case1: $|bz| <1 \iff |b| <  \frac{6}{5}.$ In this case $(x_n)$ is convergent. Case 2:  $|bz| >1 \iff |b| >  \frac{6}{5}.$ In this case $(x_n)$ is divergent. Case 3:  $|bz| =1 \iff |b| =  \frac{6}{5}.$ In this case $(x_n)$ is bounded, hence $(x_n)$ contains a convergent subsequence.

Comment: I have shown this. And that the argument is $\pi /6$. Having trouble continuing from that point.

Comment: Okay I see. Is my expression correct as I have written it for $|bz|$?

Comment: Yes, $|x_n|=|(b \cdot (\sqrt{3}\frac{5}{12}+i\frac{5}{12}))^n|.$

Comment: Greetings @Fred. For case 2. What does it mean that the $|x_n|$ goes  to infinity? What effect does that have on $x_n$ and why?

Comment: If $|x_n| \to \infty$, then $(x_n)$ is divergent and each subsequence of $(x_n)$ is also divergent.

Comment: Why does $x_n$ converge to $0$ if $|x_n|$ does. Is this a generel result?

Comment: Yes, this is a general result. Look at the definitions!